# Resize images automatically

Tags: 7, media

When I insert an image into content area it's usually larger than the content area and the pasted image overlaps with neighbouring blocks. I have to edit HTML and set `width` and `height` CSS properties.

Is it possible to configure Drupal for automatic image resizing (shrinking), so the creator of the article will only upload the image of arbitrary size?

thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you attach an image field to the content type, you can define Image Styles at `admin/config/media/image-styles`. It is the core continuation of the [Imagecache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache) module.

This may be able to be made to work for inline images using the [Media module](http://drupal.org/project/media), but YMMV.

Comment: I created style `content_image` with efect `scale width 500` in `admin/config/media/image-styles` and I checked my style `content_image` in `Administration » Structure » Content types » Event » Manage fields >> INSERT` but it is has not effect.

Comment: u will have to change your display settings on the field to use the image styles preset.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what exactly you mean, but the [Image resize filter module](http://drupal.org/project/image_resize_filter) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Go to configuration-> media -> image Styles
add a new image style and set resize/crop/scale option you want for the image size.

Go to manage display of that content type and for the field image set the image style you created. 
Your image will be using the same image style while viewing the content node.